# apt update outputs error

Tags: package-management, updates

When I write run `sudo apt-get update` on the terminal, I get this output.

```
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security InRelease [109 kB]
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic InRelease                                               
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates InRelease                               
Get:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports InRelease [99.9 kB]       
Ign:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu kinetic InRelease                  
Err:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu kinetic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::3e 443]
Traceback (most recent call last):                             
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 3, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
```

In my system, Neither the Software Updater app nor the gnome-terminal opens.

Comment: Get rid of the ppa from the sources list. https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu kinetic Release

Comment: The PPA you added does **not** provide support for *kinetic* or 22.10; PPAs are 3rd party *Personal Package Archives* which means the only security you perform as to if they're safe/helpful to your system is that you perform youself; did you check first?  A quick check of what you were adding (https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) would have told you it shouldn't be added.